# Help with video transcription

Tags: vocabulary

I'm trying to transcribe a video about modern Irish emigration, but I can't catch a little phrase from 1:43 to 1:48 ('I like the ?'). Would you be so kind as to tell me what exactly he's saying?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q8BCCFT2nv4

Comment: Not 100% sure, so I'm not going add it as an answer, but it sounds to me like he's saying "I like the donkeys, the coast, the dogs, the people - that's where you were born."

Comment: @DamienH Perhaps "the colts" in place of "the coast"?  Both work to my ear.

Comment: @jason-patterson Seems like it'd fit better, as the other things in the list are all living things.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, with the assistance of the estimable Mr Patterson, I'll venture that the text of your transcription should read:

> I like the donkeys, the colts, the dogs, the people - that's where you were born.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't coast or colts it is **COWS**.

**Source:** I am Irish.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer "coast" as he is gesturing away from himself at the point when he says it. and the context is the "place where you were born".  If it were just a list of living things, that could be anywhere.